# Transaction with its Identity increment value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to add Invoices to a database. Each invoice has a few lines.

My classes are:

```
// Mapped to Invoice DB table
public class Invoice
{
    // Mapped to IDENTITY(1,1) field
    public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public List<InvoiceLine> InvoiceLineList { get; set; }
}

// Mapped to InvoiceLines DB table
public class InvoiceLine
{
    // Must have same value as Invoice.InvoiceNumber
    public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

I need a transaction to insert records in Invoice and InvoiceLines tables in such manner:

1. One record is created in the Invoice table, and its InvoiceNumber is generated by the server (`IDENTITY(1,1)`).
2. Many records are created in the InvoiceLines table, with the above InvoiceNumber.

How can I achieve that? Is it even possible on the client side, with Entity Framework and `System.Transactions`?

Or should I use a SQL stored procedure having a transaction? If so - how to pass the `InvoiceLinesList` to a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  Just start a transaction, add the Invoice, SaveChanges().  After SaveChanges() the new invoice will have it's InvoiceNumber populated.  Use that to add InvoiceLines, SaveChanges() again and commit the transaction.

Or add navigation properties and associate them that way.  If you do that you don't need a transaction, as you'll be using a single SaveChanges(), which always runs in a transaction.